# Is it possible to define own syntax on a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, dsl, github-linguist

I'm writing a small [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), and I'm curious if it's possible to somehow show it in a language bar above the repository source where all languages are listed by percentage of using or GitHub administration needs to allow that language?

For example, I'm writing a Ruby project with the DSL called *Puppy*, and I want to show the percentage of all files with the *.puppy* extension beside other languages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you need add your language to  Linguist library (https://github.com/github/linguist) which GitHub utilize to recognize source code languages.

according to: https://help.github.com/articles/my-repository-is-marked-as-the-wrong-language/

Answer (score 9):

GitHub uses [`github/linguist`](https://github.com/github/linguist) to recognize languages, including to display which languages the project is made up of in the navigation bar.

For your `.puppy` files to be recognized by GitHub (and put in the language list), you would need to contribute to that repository.

Answer (score 1):

As Rafail Akhmetshin and intboolstring wrote, you'd need to add support for your language in the open source project [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) if you want to use it in your repository. There's however a requirements on in-the-wild usage across github.com. See [the guidelines](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#adding-a-language) for more information.

The custom language feature (being able to define a syntax without having to first add support for it in Linguist) has been requested twice on the Linguist repository: [#2627](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2627) and [#2598](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2598). There are, however, some technical and legal concerns to address before this could be implemented (see [#2627](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2627) in particular).